# Android mapquest geocoder country-setting

Tags: android, geocoding, mapquest

Since I own an app key for mapquest (community edition), all geocoding requests end up in US only. Before I entered the app key geocoding european locations was possible.

I couldn't find a method to set a default country. Even initializing the geocoder object with a Locale didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the mapquest Android API doesn't support single line international geocoding.

This is the reply I got from mapquest:

> I checked at our Android API is still using our v1 geocoder which does
>   not support single line international geocoding.  My support suggested
>   you use our geocoding web service for the geocoding first:
>   http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/geocoding-ws 
>   Again just make sure the request says “v2”.